# How to register a provider in Jersey 1.x via ResourceConfig?

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-1.0

As `com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig` doesn't contain '`register`' method.

I want to register `ContainerResponseFilter` programmatically.

I also tried to register it via `@Provider` annotation:

```
@Provider
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest containerRequest) {

        return containerRequest;
    }
    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest containerRequest, ContainerResponse containerResponse) {

        return containerResponse;
    }
}
```

But it's not triggered.

Update:

In web.xml:

```
 <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>rest.providers</param-value>
  </init-param>
```

In server's log I see:

> com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init     INFO: No
>   provider classes found.

Update2:
Added class:

```
public class MyApplication  extends ResourceConfig{


    public MyApplication(){
        getProviderClasses().add(LoggingFilter.class);
    }
```

constructor was not triggered.

In server Log I see:

```
Mar 28, 2018 3:46:47 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  rest.services
Mar 28, 2018 3:46:47 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class rest.services.RestRes1
Mar 28, 2018 3:46:47 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Mar 28, 2018 3:46:47 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
```

it only finds package with resources but not providers.

Update 3:

If I explicitly define my provider class in web.xml,

```
  <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>rest.services.MyFilter</param-value>
  </init-param>
```

It works fine.

But I need to do it programmatically.

Comment: The parameter name should be `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the following methods for registering providers in Jersey 1.x:

- [`getProviderClasses()`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/1.19.1/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig.html#getProviderClasses()): Get the set of provider classes.
- [`getProviderSingletons()`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/1.19.1/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig.html#getProviderSingletons()): Get the set of provider singleton instances.

Alternatively you could use [`PackagesResourceConfig`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/1.19.1/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/PackagesResourceConfig.html) to scan and register the resource and provider classes from one or more packages:

```
@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class MyApplication extends PackagesResourceConfig {

     public MyApplication() {
         super("org.foo.rest;org.bar.rest");
     }    
}
```

Jersey offers a few deployment options according you environment. Check the [documentation](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/1.19.1/jax-rs.html) for details.

Comment: I updated my question, regarding your answer,
I should just add my provider class to getProviderClasses()?

Comment: Do I need to register MyApplication ?

Comment: Where are `ContainerRequestFilter` and `ContainerResponseFilter` imported from?

Comment: com.sun.jersey.spi.container